How to display local storage data first and replace it with remote data using InfiniteScrollPagination in Flutter?
I'm using the infinite_scroll_pagination package in Flutter, and I need help implementing a pattern where:
I first display some items from local storage as a page.
Once I fetch the remote data from an API, I want to replace the local data with the up-to-date remote data.
I want to implement this following best practices, but I’m not sure of the correct approach.
I've tried using notifyListeners() on the PagingController, like this:
dart
Copy code
event.pagingController.notifyListeners();
However, this doesn’t seem like the best solution. Could someone guide me on the proper way to handle this situation?
